# Hibernate Criteria to load column with max value on another column for each group

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I only have experience using Hibernate criteria in a simple way. Now I am facing a issue to load data of a column when the record has max value on another column for each group.

The scenario is like this. I have table A and B and am going to join them. However, I only want to fetch A's column values and the value of column 1 in table B when column 2 in B is the max in each group, while the records are grouped based on columns in A.

Can someone give me an example or suggestion? Please note that my only option is using criteria, no raw sql or hsql. Thanks in advance.